# IMvcBuilder doesn't contain a definition for it Fro AddRazorRuntimeCompilation

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am using MVC Core and I am trying to add `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`   but it reports that IMvcBuilder doesn't contain a definition for it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` package ?

Answer (score 1):

The `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`extension method is in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` nuget package. Make sure you have this included in your project.

Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` NuGet package.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation -Version 6.0.4
```

Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) to know more.